# Trying to add breakpoint lines from strucchange to a plot by "lines" command

Tags: r, plot, line, breakpoints

Here is my data (dts_trend):

```
> dput(dts_trend)
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.47369471844927, 2.41350194043744, 
31.2688751629577, 60.4339814569159, 60.8815312225206, 66.6038819904373, 
73.156936755854, 76.816641271267, 85.1805735775133, 91.3915452305811, 
99.6531480201115, 117.065779757539, 127.934628844144, 131.9009947727, 
109.697404628818, 94.2178211280514, 105.269315312447, 105.656646918218, 
105.456594598961, 104.86750404063, 103.80636752938, 104.010655493502, 
99.6228424644946, 89.3697490054001, 83.3412326343076, 86.2617376700135, 
116.606572326867, 138.064609693093, 143.601054498899, 158.668783559584, 
161.591992526748, 169.441389157163, 175.860044251329, 176.644686824612, 
178.941999101815, 185.055281292826, 199.863946750333, 207.848664059284, 
185.42263986779, 165.511071516482, 157.699795921503, 145.289484863146, 
145.516461259322, 145.644524797912, 147.611673512811, 151.784984700691, 
186.149216214556, 213.288955430274, 203.160103824044, 196.032345550358, 
184.815433509085, 186.410986310432, 193.645954254931, 190.143864842133, 
186.917926013241, 214.249350239138, 235.68370719541, 227.981549937166, 
206.199821688605, 183.396956592286, 178.872793434836, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(73L, 1L), .Tsp = c(2011.91666666667, 
2017.91666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

I want to find breakpoints and use package Strucchange for it, as in an example about Nile data on page:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-look-at-strucchange-and-segmented/

(when  do the Nile example from this page, everything goes fine)

Here is my code:

```
library(strucchange)

plot(dts_trend) # the plot is shown ok

bp.dts_trend <- breakpoints(dts_trend ~1) # defining breakpoints

ci.dts_trend <- confint(bp.dts_trend, breaks = 3)

lines(ci.dts_trend)
```

Then problem is that last line of code shows no lines.

Only if I do:

```
plot.new()

lines(ci.dts_trend)
```

I see three vertical lines on the blank plot...

And I am struggling to see original plot with my dts_trend data and these three lines on it.

Comment: The problem is missing values in your data; using `na.omit(dts_trend)` from the beginning would work.

Comment: Julius, thank you very much! Sorry for duplicate question, I am really new to R. You really have helped me a lot! By the way, where can I read about my mistake, I mean about missing values in terms of plotting? Is it due to my original plot included missing values, and breakpoint plot has less values?

Comment: In general, plotting and missing values by themselves are fine. The problem here is that, as you can read in the linked question, when there are missing values, `breakpoints` returns a different output, which no longer works as expected in certain cases, such as plotting.